# silence detection not working Asterisk AGI

Tags: asterisk, voip, agi

I'm trying to record a call in Asterisk, I used the function `record_file` but it does not work properly. The silence detection is not working, the call keep alive without detecting the 3 silence seconds. But when I dial "#", the record is created properly.

```
agi.record_file("test", format="wav", escape_digits="#",timeout=-1, silence = 3, beep="beep")
```

Does anyone know how I could use the silence detection properly?

Comment: You have 5th question or something like that with "xxx not working on asterisk". All working. Just read doc.

Comment: I don't wanna bother anyone of you. If all were working I'd have not asked these questions. In doc, there is included the way to use the command (for example in this case "record_file") and its parameters but I'm saying that the silence detection is not working for me for any reason.

Comment: In doc it say "see dsp.conf"

Comment: Say some features(used by millions of installs) not working when it DO work is not nice idea.

Comment: I was having an issue with silence when recording calls in with asterisk. What I found was the wav file was not growing during gaps of silence this is because asterisk was not transmitting silence. The fix I found was in the asterisk.conf `transmit_silence` set that to yes and restart asterisk.

Comment: I set "transmit_silence" yes in the specified file. The silence detection seems to work properly but the call hangs up immediately just after recording.